# Monitor DVI Adapter

Tags: display, dvi

I'm attempting to hook up dual monitors on my laptop's docking station. I have one VGA connection and 2 DVI on the docking station. I have an VGA to DVI converter as shown in the pic below; however, the docking station doesn't accept the 4 pins around the bar on the right. Do I need a different adapter? Or can I remove those pins?

[image: Adapter:]

Comment: when you say "HD connection" - do you mean VGA? (example: http://www.lindy.co.uk/vga-female-to-female-adapter/71242.html )

Comment: Yes, sorry, I don't have my terminology all nailed down... I'll change the question.

Comment: Ok - do you think you could lay out clearly how many monitors you're aiming to connect, and what connectors they require?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the docking station only has a DVI-D Connector. This means it doesn't output the analog signal needed by your VGA monitor. This image shows the types of DVI connectors.

[image: DVI Connectors]

A passive adapter (As shown in your photo) won't work here. It needs a DVI-A or DVI-I output.

If you can find an active adapter, that will take the digital signal and convert it to analog, that might work. Or, buy a new monitor that can accept a DVI signal.

Comment: The active adapters are generally expensive though. The cheap ones (No external power) tend to burn out quickly, sometimes in minutes or hours. The ones with external power are better, the only ones I would buy start at about $50. For that price your halfway to a decent new monitor.

Comment: Wow, yeah, for sure. Would it be fair to say that a monitor without this connection is old/outdated?

Comment: It might be time to start looking at an upgrade. On the other hand, looking at Dell's website, their cheapest monitors still come with VGA input only. VGA isn't dead yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from another source:

There 2 different styles...DVI and DVI-D. DVI has the extra pins...the docking station is expecting DVI-D.